# How to compare two instance variables within a method?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I run into a problem comparing the variable age between 2 objects. The method `fight()` should return the winner which is basically the one who is older.

However, the compiler returns:

> < identifier > expected in line 20

Here is my code:

```
public class Walter
{

int age;
int weight;
int id;

Walter(int sAge, int sWeight, int sId)
    {
    age = sAge;
    weight = sWeight;
    id = sId;
    }

public String toString()
    {
    return "\nWalter #" + id + "\nAge: " + age + "\nWeight: " + weight + "\n";
    }

public String fight(Walter, aWalter)
    {
    if(Walter(age)>aWalter(age))
        {       
        return "The winner is #1";
        }
        else
        {
        return "The winner is #2";
        }

    }

public static void main (String[]args)
    {
    Walter a = new Walter(20,75,1);
    Walter b = new Walter(10,25,2);
    Walter c = new Walter(1,7,3);

    System.out.println("omg\n"+a+b+c);

    fight(a,b);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much Java, but I think the definition line for your fight method is wrong, you probably want something like `public String fight(Walter waltera, Walter walterb)`, so you give the type and a name for each provided argument and then your `if` statement would reference each of the two provided Walter instances accordingly (something like `if(waltera(age) > walterb(age)`?). Welcome to SO!

Comment: @3N1GM4 It would be `waltera.age > walterb.age` or if you create a getter-method `waltera.getAge() > walterb.getAge()`.

Comment: @Gendarme ah yes, thanks - sorry for giving bad guidance (hence why it was a comment and not an answer)! I also missed that this is a method of `Walter`, so only needs to have one additional `Walter` object passed in the arguments, not two! I'll crawl back over to `[tsql]` now, my `java` is definitely too rusty to be much help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fight method call was passing 2 objects of type Walter, but when you were comparing the age of these 2 objects of type walter in the fight method there was a syntax error at line 20 where you had to specify two arguments of type walter. I have corrected and written the correct code that will execute without errors.

Code:

```
public class Exceptiontest
```

{

```
int age;
int weight;
int id;

Exceptiontest(int sAge, int sWeight, int sId)
{
  age = sAge;
  weight = sWeight;
  id = sId;
}

public String toString()
{
   return "\nWalter #" + id + "\nAge: " + age + "\nWeight: " + weight + "\n";
}

public static String fight(Exceptiontest aWalter,Exceptiontest bWalter)
{
    if(aWalter.age > bWalter.age)
    {       
    return "The winner is #1";
    }
    else
    {
    return "The winner is #2";
    }

}

public static void main (String[]args)
{
  Exceptiontest a = new Exceptiontest(20,75,1);
  Exceptiontest b = new Exceptiontest(10,25,2);
  Exceptiontest c = new Exceptiontest(1,7,3);



   System.out.println(fight(a,b));

}
```

}

Comment: Oh my god, thank you ! There are just 2 questions left. 1: Why do i have to use static in my fight method ( public static String fight ). 2: Would the definition in the fight bracket ( Walter aWalter, Walter bWalter) look like this (Walter aWalter bWalter, Walter cWalter dWalter) i if wanted to compare two mamber values?

Comment: See static methods are those that are executed without instantiating a class, this static method in your code can be replaced as: public void fight(Walter a,walter b), but when calling this method you need to call it with an object of a class. No the above defintion you mentioned is invalid from my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You access member value is by using the `.` operator, not brackets. Additionally, there's a problem in the method's definition - there's a redundant comma between "Walter" and "aWalter". Regardless of the compilation issues, it's also worth noting the logical problem in your code - you don't handle two instances with the same age:

```
public String fight(Walter aWalter) {
    // Comma removed -----^

    if (age > aWalter.age) { // Access fixed here
        return "The winner is #1";
    } else if (age < aWalter.age) { // Missing logic fixed here
        return "The winner is #2";
    } else {
        return "Tie";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method is supposed to get a parameter of type `Walter`... but you're not passing one. You should right the method like this:

```
public String fight(Walter aWalter)
{
    if(age>aWalter.age)
    {       
        return "The winner is #1";
    }
    else
    {
        return "The winner is #2";
    }

}
```

Method declarations can't have a nameless variable (i.e. just a type, such as `Walter` which is what you've done)